# Trouble connecting to SVN server

Tags: eclipse, svn, subversive

I'm new to SVN but I managed to install a server on my server and get it to load the respositories from the web (using uberSVN) but when I try to connect to it in eclipse using Subversive I keep getting am error reading "svn: handshake failed, received: ' " For my url I'm using "svn://mydomain.com:3690/svn" I have no problem connecting to the server through TortoiseSVN so I know the problem is not with the server. I know this is a noob question, but any help is greatly appreciated :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure the svn client used in Eclipse is compatible with the svn version for the server. Also check TortoiseSVN version and compare with what you got in Eclipse. Per my experience, there are some major incompatibilities between SVN 1.4.x and 1.6.x.

Comment: The server is running SVN version 1.6.17, Subversive and the version of TortoiseSVN I'm using are both connecting to SVN 1.6.x versions.

Comment: Okay I found the problem. The version of SVN Kit I had installed only worked up to SVN 1.6.15, I installed the newest version of SVN Kit which works with SVN 1.6.17 but I can't figure out how to make Subversive use it, any ideas?

Comment: See item 8 in this page: http://eclipse.org/subversive/documentation/gettingStarted/aboutSubversive/install.php

Comment: That's great, but the newest version of SVN kit isn't showing up on that list for me.

Comment: Looks like a transient issue. try restarting Eclipse, or uninstalling the previous SVNkit. Other than that not sure what can be done.

Comment: I figured it out, I had to update Subversive to the unstable "Early Access" version in order to get the right SVN connector. Thanks for all your help :)